# How to display a bilingual upgrade warning for old browsers only with html+css?

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements, joomla2.5, multilingual

I have a bilingual website (English+Greek) in Joomla 2.5 and I want to display a warning for prompting visitors with old browsers to upgrade them. However, I want to target each language using an "if/else" so I can display a message in the corresponding language, that means English for the english-speaking visitors and Greek for the Greek-speaking ones.

I looked for this solution at bilingual sites who display that code but almost all of them use javascript, something I do not wish as I am looking ways to unburden my website from that. And Googled it of course.
My idea was to do something like this. Forgive my php code, I don't know much.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
if <xhtml xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">
<p>My English text here</p>
else {
<p>My greek text here</p>}
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) or considered so far?

Comment: makes any sense now @Jeroen?